# Should the 'positive question record' for Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic be modified?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, badges

First off, I'm not here to just whine about my `< 0.5` question record, but I believe there is a real proposition that many users could benefit from.

To earn the Curious badge, you must have asked 5 well-recieved questions on different days, but the hard part can be having a positive question record, above `0.5` in the formula of `(total questions - negative questions - closed questions - deleted questions) / total questions`. This can be a problem for users who started off rough with many downvoted and closed questions, making it sometimes almost impossible for them to earn the badge unless they are very active.

I believe that all mistakes should be forgiven, and I believe that the positive question requirement for Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic should be modified in some way.

Comment: I still don't have the curious badge. The badge criteria is fine as it is.

Comment: You are missing the *whole point* of the badge. It is there to reward those that manage to not start out rough. Even starting of rough can easily be compensated for by making sure that going forward your questions do fit the site's purpose once you've learned what that is. If your 'rough period' contains many badly received questions, then it is only correct that it'll take longer to correct for, and that's really by design.

Comment: For your own situation, you need another 6 positively received questions, I think (deleted + closed + downvoted is 11 right now, so 0.5 is at 22 questions, you have 16 now).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for the explanation + calculation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, this is not going to be changed. As the [original proposal for the badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) states:

> The takeaway is that people can't sweep past indiscretions under the rug by deleting them. And they can recover from a bad start as long as they don't ask more bad questions.

If you have a rough start on the site, it is still perfectly possible to recover from that, by asking good questions again to offset the bad. That's only fair.